# Spring boot autoconfigure application start fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've built my own starter and the autoconfigure step fails with dependency conflict.

These are the spring boot versions both my starter and upstream project are using

'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version2.1.8.RELEASE

'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '2.4.1'

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.lambda$addResourceHandlers$0(W
ebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:411)
The following method did not exist:
    'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.Re
sourceHandlerRegistration.addResourceLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource[])'
The method's class, org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration, is available from the following loca
tions:
    jar:file:/opt/eureka/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandl
erRegistration.class
The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration: jar:file:/opt/eureka/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-we
bmvc-5.3.2.jar!/
Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.servlet.config.an
notation.ResourceHandlerRegistration
```

Answer (score 2):

From your log I see one of two possible problems:

1. Somewhere you override spring-webmvc-5.3.2 to a higher or lower version
2. Problem in your starter code (if it configure your WebMvc)

Try `mvn dependency:tree` or `gradle dependencies` to explore dependencies.
Attached your starter code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use spring boot 2.4.1 to avoid the conflict.